# SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed error

Tags: java, jdbc

Im getting this error and I don´t know why: SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed .
The error appears at line        while(rs1.next()){

```
private void tablaPeliculasMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    int codigo=Integer.parseInt(tablaPeliculas.getValueAt(tablaPeliculas.getSelectedRow(),0).toString());
    System.out.println("codigo: "+codigo);
    String nombre="";

    ResultSet rs1=DBVideoteca.consultaPortada(codigo);
    try {
        while(rs1.next()){
            nombre=rs1.getObject("imagen").toString();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Videoteca.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and consultaPortada method:

```
static ResultSet consultaPortada(int cod){
 conn=enlace(conn);
    try{
        stt=conn.prepareStatement("select * from peliculas where codigo=?");
        stt.setInt(1, cod);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
   {
    System.out.println("excepcion del try 1º del metodo consulta portada");
   }
   try 
   {
    stt.executeQuery();
   }
   catch (SQLException ex)
   {
    System.out.println("error en la query " + ex);
   }

   //cerrarConexion();
   return rs;
}
```

Comment: where do you open you connection?

Comment: Are you working in a multi threaded environment like a web application or a back end service application? If so, then you **should not** have `static` methods to retrieve the database results.

Comment: use rs = stt.executeQuery(); in your code, the result set (rs) variable is unassigned, and hence you have empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `consultaPortada` you return `rs` which is never actually assigned.

Change this line:

```
stt.executeQuery();
```

To:

```
rs = stt.executeQuery();
```

And your issue should go away.

Answer (score 1):

I have many concerns over your code
 First the answer to your question is that you are not assigning values to rs
So, change

```
stt.executeQuery();
```

To:

```
rs = stt.executeQuery();
```

Secondly, your function is badly written

```
static ResultSet consultaPortada(int cod){
 conn=enlace(conn);
    try{
        stt=conn.prepareStatement("select * from peliculas where codigo=?");
        stt.setInt(1, cod);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
   {
    System.out.println("excepcion del try 1º del metodo consulta portada");//caught an exception here
   }
   try 
   {
    stt.executeQuery(); // this should not be executed if there is an exception in above try block
   }
   catch (SQLException ex)
   {
    System.out.println("error en la query " + ex);
   }

   //cerrarConexion();
   return rs;
}
```

you `stt.executeQuery();` statement should be also in previous block something like this

```
 try{
stt=conn.prepareStatement("select * from peliculas where codigo=?");
stt.setInt(1, cod);
stt.executeQuery();
}
catch (SQLException ex)
{
System.out.println("excepcion del try 1º del metodo consulta portada");
}
```

Third, Always close connection in `finally` block

Comment: My biggest concern is that OP uses the same `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` variables in all the application. If this happens to be a multi threaded environment, then the `rs = stt.executeQuery();` would be a minor problem.

Comment: Yes Luiggi I am getting to it. though I am sharing my knowledge on best practices. I have little knowledge about multithreading in Java. I will try to address your concern too

Comment: To put it simple: you have two operation, one retrieves a `List<Foo>` and the other a `List<Bar>`. User A (like you) and user B (like me) are connected to the application (e.g. StackOverflow) and want to retrieve our results, A requests for `List<Foo>` and B requests for `List<Bar>`, but since we're using the same `Connection`, same `PreparedStatement` and same `ResultSet`, a race condition will fire and both A and B will get `List<Foo>` or `List<Bar>`, or if the application is really bad designed then one of them will receive an exception and the other the (un)desired results.

Comment: But the OP uses `conn=enlace(conn);` in the function. which means for every call he is creating a new connection ( unless the function is implementing singleton ). And, even DBs can handle multiple connections that is why we have singletons..so sharing same conn variable among different thread should not be a problem right?

Comment: Note that it is a `static` method, so all class fields used in the method should be `static` as well. Also, the `PreparedStatement stt` is `static` and is shared in all the application. If you call the same method `consultaPortada` in at least two threads running in parallel, one of them will reinitialize this variable (even if using different physical database connections) and the resultant `ResultSet rs` (also `static`) will be reinitialized as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    try{
       rs = stt.executeQuery();
   }
   catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("error en la query " + ex);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check if `!rs.isClosed()` in while loop condition itself

Answer (score 0):

it seems before calling `consultaPortada()` you had previously assigned some value to `rs` and you had closed that `ResultSet` object. and since it is a closed resultset it is throwing this error.

assuming you are trying to assign  `stt.executeQuery();` to the result set try this

```
 rs = stt.executeQuery();
```